# Transpiling ActiveRecord objects to TypeScript types for non-mono repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, typescript, react-native, activerecord

I've recently started development on what will be come a rather large mobile application (React Native) that consumes a Ruby on Rails API (in API mode).

On the frontend I've used TypeScript extensively throughout the code but I am having issues with how to approach building types and interfaces for data received through API requests. I've heard about transpiling C# database models into TypeScript types - but I can't find anything similar for Ruby on Rails. The only thing I've been able to find is how to handle types in mono-repos where both the frontend and backend is in a single repository.

I could build my types manually on the frontend but I feel like this wouldn't be sustainable over the long term, especially when new developers join the project.

Is there any gems out there for this or would I have to write it myself? Am I approaching the issue incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could build my types manually on the frontend

This is probably the best choice as it encourages decoupling between the frontend and the backend API application. The whole idea of automatically generating front end code based on your database sounds good in theory but your frontend is not talking directly to the DB - its talking to your API and should have no knowledge of the underlying data storage which is an implementation detail of the API.

This is also the reason why you only see this attempted in a monorepo - it requires a tight coupling which is very undesirable. If the backend schema changes it will break clients - which would not occur if they simply communicate through a versioned API. As long as the API remains consistent the clients are isolated to a very large degree from changes on the backend and can occur in tandem.

You also have to take into consideration that ActiveRecord is extremely dynamic compared to anything written in C# and most other frameworks. Model attributes are automatically defined at runtime by reading the schema directly from the database - its all superninja level metaprogramming. So you can't use any form of static analysis to create frontend code from the backend code alone.